# My code in Apps Script works on browsers but not on the FB app

Tags: facebook, google-apps-script

I have a script on Apps Script that randomly redirects people who click on the web app link to one of two surveys. The link works well from a browser, but it gives an *undefined* error when opened through FB app.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoaBU.png)

This is the code:

```
function doGet() {
   var webpages = [];
   //---------------just change the webpage URLs
   //the webpages need to be hosted on https sites - if you want more than two just create a new line using the same code as below
   //just change the link to the google form
   webpages.push("link 1");
   webpages.push("link 2");
   //------------------------------------------
   var random_page = Math.floor(Math.random() * webpages.length);
   var redirect = webpages[random_page];


   // Log the chosen page URL
   Logger.log('Redirecting to: ' + redirect);


   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>location.href = '" + redirect + "';</script>");
}
```

I checked and it is not a iOS or Android issue. The links in the script are correct. The error appears only when the link is opened through the FB App.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please, _what_ exactly is supposed to be undefined here?

Comment: Just edited the post and included a screenshot of the error

Comment: So it just shows undefined as actual "page content" then, apparently. Not sure how that could happen, with the code shown so far. Even if `redirect` was undefined (you're trying to log the value to somewhere there, have you checked what that resulted in?) assigning that to `location.href` would not make this should up as page content, it should set the URL to contain `undefined` at the end. (Whether you app might _create_ body content saying "undefined" based on such an URL path then, I don't know.)